# Spring Data JPA How to pass a date parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I'm working in a spring MVC project and spring data with spring tools suite, I want to pass a date argument to a native query, I have this so far.

My query method inside a interface that extends JpaRepository

```
 @Query(value  = 
            "SELECT "
                + "a.name, a.lastname
            + "FROM "
                + "person  a, "
                + "myTable b "
            + "WHERE "
            + "a.name= ?1' "
            + "AND a.birthday = ?2 ",
         nativeQuery = true)
    public ArrayList<Object> personInfo(String name, String dateBirthDay);
```

The method that implements this interface definition:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getPersonsList(String name, String dateBirthDay) {

            ArrayList<Object> results= null;

            results= serviceAutowiredVariable.personInfo(name, dateBirthDay);

            return results;
        }
```

and this is how I call it from my controller class.

```
personsList= _serviceAutowiredVariable.getPersonsList("Jack", "TO_DATE('01-08-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')" );
```

I suppose that in this line `"AND a.birthday = ?2 "`   the `?2`is equals to this string `TO_DATE('01-08-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

but I am getting this error when I run my code

```
    [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet] root cause
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: Just pass a `Date` object instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use such construction:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
...

@Query(value  = 
    " SELECT a.id, a.lastname FROM person a" + 
    " WHERE a.name = :name AND a.birthday = :date ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> getPersonInfo(
    @Param("name") String name, 
    @Param("date") Date date);
```

Comment: I made typo mistake - getPersonInfo takes 2 arguments: of type String and Date of course. I have just edited to fix this.